# Optimize distinct values on a large number of columns

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to compute distinct values for a large number of columns (>20,000). I am now using pyspark.sql.functions.approxCountDistinct() to get an approximation for each column's distinct count. That is super fast (HyperLogLog). After that, if the distinct count is below some threshold (like 10), we want the values. I have a loop that does this.

```
distinct_values_list[cname] = df.select(cname).distinct().collect()
```

It is extremely slow as most of the time, I have many columns to process, could be half the columns (10K). Is there no way to make spark do many columns at a time? Seems like it will only parallelize each column but unable to do many columns at once.

Appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: How many rows are there in your table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated)
Not sure, it is fast enough but you may want to try

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(*[
    F.collect_set(c).alias(c)
    for c in LIST_10k_COLS
]).collect()
```

Comment: This approach isn't going to work because each column will have different number of distinct values so the dimensionality of what's return will be different for each column. If there were some way to tell the dataframe to just fill out the missing values with some NULL value, that would be ideal but I don't know if there's a way. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have only 2 values in each column. Then the number of unique combinations is 2^20000 =~ 10^7000. This is 1 with 7000 zeroes. If there are more than 2 values in some columns, this number will be even higher.

1. Revise your model. Are all columns really independent? Can it be that many of these columns just represent different values of the same dimension? Then may be you can essentially reduce the number of columns.
2. Consider if you are using the proper tool. May be some completely different approaches (Neo4j, ...) suit better?